# Programmatically create new customer and assign current quote

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, magento-1.7.0.1

I want to create customer programmatically and want to assign current login customer quote but unable to do that. Here is script, Please see and help me.

```
// create customer 

$websiteId = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();            
$store = Mage::app()->getStore();
$firstname ="Firstname";
$lastname = "Lastname";
$email = "test@test.com";

$customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
$customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
         ->setStore($store)                         
         ->setFirstname($firstname)                                         
         ->setLastname($lastname)
         ->setEmail($email) 
         ->setPassword('test123');

$customer->save();  
$customer_id = $customer->getId();  

// quote assign to new customer 
$session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
$current_quote_id = $session->getQuoteId();
$currentQuote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($current_quote_id);
$currentQuoteItem = $currentQuote->getAllItems();

$newQuote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');
$newQuote->assignCustomer($customer);
$newQuote->addItem($currentQuoteItem);
$newQuote->setQuote($newQuote);
$newQuote->collectTotals()->save();
```

Above script is creating the customer but not assinging the quote in customer's account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

This script works. Tested.

```
try {
    // create customer 
    $websiteId = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
    $firstname = "Firstname";
    $lastname = "Lastname";
    $email = "test@test.com";
    $password = "test123";

    $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
    $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
             ->setStore($store)
             ->setFirstname($firstname)
             ->setLastname($lastname)
             ->setEmail($email)
             ->setPassword($password);
    $customer->save();

    // set customer as logged in
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
    $session->login($email,$password);

    // quote assign to new customer
    $quoteObj = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');
    $quoteObj->assignCustomer($customer);
    $quoteObj->setStoreId($store->getId());
    $quoteObj->collectTotals();
    $quoteObj->setIsActive(true);
    $quoteObj->save();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    var_dump($ex->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Thanks you ! But i want to assign current login customer quote to newly added customer. Can you please help me !

Comment: I have updated the script, please check this one and let me to sort it out

Comment: I test this script on my test site and it worked. Result: created client, logged in and added product to the quote.

Comment: I think, you are going in different scenario. My scenario is as a customer i logged in, added product to cart then i just want to push my all the cart into newly add customer which has recently added.

Comment: You changed the previous script where you added a product, but anyway if you do not want to add a specific product, you can simply delete `$quoteItem` and `$productObj` and the function will only create a customer, it will log in the customer and assign the current quote.

Comment: Thank you! Previous scripts worked as you suggested. I will try it and let you know for the same.

Comment: "setCustomerAsLoggedIn" call is not necessary. It's included in "login" method. So you don't have to load the customer again after customer save.
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
$session->login($email,$password);

Comment: Yes @Franc, I have already corrected the answer

Answer (score 0):

It create issue because you `$store_id` is null in your case, try with some realistic `store id` and check it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply But it is still not working.

Comment: i have updated the code.

Comment: pass $storeid as 1 and try, it's working fine in my system.

Comment: I have updated the script, please check this one and let me to sort it out